# SQL reorder index for table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm not sure how to word this question but I have a sql table like so:

```
Order | ID  | Name |
-----------------------
17    |8DFdf| Jake |
18    |8DLAS| Mike |
19    |144DF| John |
```

and I want to insert a new row into the table but I need to keep the order indexed, is there a way for me to re-order all the rows below the inserted one?

```
Row to insert : 18 | LDLA93 | Smith
```

Table after insert:

```
Order | ID    | Name |
-----------------------
17    |8DFdf  | Jake |
18    |LDLA93 | Smith|
19    |8DLAS  | Mike |
20    |144DF  | John |
```

Comment: is Order a column in your table?

Comment: yes it's a column not the primary key

Comment: is this mysql or sqlserver. Can't be both

Answer (score 1):

Try with this approach:

```
update `Table` set `Order` = `Order` + 1 where `Order` >= 18;
insert into `Table` set `Order` = 18, `Id` = 'LDLA93', `Name` = 'Smith';
```

Comment: Remember Order is keyword so you have to use backtick

Comment: if there is a unique index on Order this might fail. You probably need to quote Order since it is a reserved word.

Comment: I added backticks. The queries are here just to explain the technique anyway :)